# VSCode inserts spaces before chained functions on newline

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, formatter

On windows 10 with

```bash
λ code-insiders.cmd --version
1.69.0-insider
0e3304bca9e862eddc7e437e2bab8a4a4a4f33c9
x64
```

With the default formatter if I have something like this:

```
    await new VersionNumberUpdater(
      interval,
      url
    )
    .start(
      () => result.next(UpdateResult.NewVersionFound)
    )
```

Format on save turns it into

```
    await new VersionNumberUpdater(
      interval,
      url
    )
      .start(
        () => result.next(UpdateResult.NewVersionFound)
      );
```

And I don't want that. I want the first and I can't seem to find the setting that turns this off, except turning off format on save. I don't want to turn format on save off but this is driving me nuts :v

Comment: do you have prettier extension enabled?

Comment: Nope. I've gone so far to not even have it installed :v